# Changing specific array value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let bdays = ["10-17", "05-19", "20-19"];
```

how do i change the '-' in that array to '/'.

Comment: iterate over the array doing a string replace

Comment: i already do forEach, after that i split with '-' and join them with '/'.

Comment: your code does NONE of that - all you've shown is the variable - you probably think your code is replacing the value in the array, but in fact it's doing nothing

Comment: `bdays.map(e=> e.replace('-', '/'))`

Comment: i do like this. const[a,b,c] =bdays; . after that i do let day1 = a.replace('-', '/');. its work, but is it the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `Array.map` to create a new array of formatted values

```
let bdays = ["10-17", "05-19", "20-19"];``
let formattedBdays = bdays.map((date) => { 
    return date.replace('-','/')
});
console.log(formattedBdays);
```

Gives Output

```
['10/17', '05/19', '20/19']
```

You can learn more about map in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

```
let bdays = ["10-17", "05-19", "20-19"];``
for( let bday of bdays) {
    bdays[bdays.indexOf(bday)]= bday.replace('-','/');
}
```